# Remotely viewing the screen provided by /dev/fb0

Tags: linux, vnc, framebuffer

I am writing a Forth for RISC V (don't ask!) - and want to add framebuffer access, but I am struggling.

The RISC V box is running Linux and is in another room and is not plugged into a monitor and I just access it via SSH.

I have now written some Forth code that manipulates the framebuffer and it runs smoothly but I cannot see any output.

Obviously just using X means I am looking at the framebuffer output of my local machine and not the remote. I tried using VNC (tightvnc) but that doesn't seem to work either - as it's X/11 based?

Is there a way of getting this to work - ie remotely viewing the screen provided by /dev/fb0 - in this sort of setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TigerVNC server programs are X11-based ('Xvnc' hosts an X11 server, 'x11vnc' attaches to an existing X11 server and scrapes its buffer), but overall VNC is not inherently tied to X11.

https://github.com/ponty/framebuffer-vncserver is a VNC server that supports reading out of the fb0 device. The current version seems to have problems with forwarding *input,* however, but it works as a view-only server. (Also, expect some constant CPU usage as it needs to continuously re-check for framebuffer changes.)

A "KVM-over-IP" device connected to the box (in place of a monitor) would be the more common solution. While most IP KVM devices are quite expensive, PiKVM might be an option.

But if your code is properly designed, it should be using an abstraction layer for graphics output (such as SDL) rather than being directly tied to /dev/fb0 interface – which would then allow you to make it draw to an X11 or Wayland window instead (and both X11 and Wayland can be tunneled over SSH to your local machine). All you'd need to do is run `ssh -Y riscbox ./goforth` and have it pop up locally.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. To be clear, though, I am already running the Forth over SSH (and X/11). I am extending the Forth to include graphics primatives rather than writing an interface for a library. The framebuffer is already an abstraction and that's what I want to target.

Comment: Then honestly it doesn't sound like it's an abstraction at the right layer if it forces you to rely on a specific OS interface; graphics primitives shouldn't care whether they're working on a fbdev or on an X11 pixmap... (which has always been "X11" as in "X Window System, version 11", neither "IBM X/11" nor "DEC X-11".)

Comment: Anyway it works, so thanks for that. The aim of using Forth is to give users something as close to the metal as I can without having to rewrite lots of OS code - so they can more easily program the sorts of devices that attached to SBCs.